# jQuery swap Next/Previous image, images in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, image, swap

I have a literal array of image IDs and I need to swap them in `<img src="">` to Next or Previous image on buttons click events. The initial current image ID is known from the `img src` provided server-side on initial page load.

Obviously, before swapping, the URL needs to be constructed with the target ID like this:

```
'http://site.com/images/' + imageID + '.jpg'
```

I'm a JS/jQuery beginner and would like to learn a correct, minimalistic approach. TIA.

My code to start off:

```
var images=["777777","666666","555555"];
var max = $(images).length;

$('#swapnextimg').click{
   $("#imageswap").attr('src', ...... );
}

<a id="swapnextimg"></a>
<a id="swapprevsimg"></a>
<div id="imagebox">
    <img id="imageswap" src="http://site.com/images/123456.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: What work have you done so far? Show us and we can work with you from there.

Comment: what buttons, what array?  some html details needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ndFGL/

```
$(function() {
    // Image ID array
    var images = ['240', '260', '250', '123', '200'];
    var max = images.length;

    // Get current image src
    var curSrc = $('#imageswap').attr('src');

    // Find ID in image src
    var curID = curSrc.replace(/.*\/(.*?)\.jpg/i, '$1');

    var curIdx = 0;

    // Search image list for index of current ID
    while (curIdx < max) {
        if (images[curIdx] == curID) {
            break;
        }
        curIdx++;
    }

    // For convenience
    var imgSrcBase = 'http://placehold.it/';

    // Next image on button (and image) click
    $('#swapnextimg,#imageswap').click( function() {
        curIdx = (curIdx+1) % max;
        $("#imageswap").attr('src', imgSrcBase+images[curIdx]+'.jpg');
    });

    // Prev image on button click
    $('#swapprevsimg').click( function() {
        curIdx = (curIdx+max-1) % max;
        $("#imageswap").attr('src', imgSrcBase+images[curIdx]+'.jpg');
    });

});
```

Comment: Why did you use 'curIdx < max' instead of 'curIdx <= max' please? Isn't your while loop missing the last element in array?

Comment: curIdx is zero-based, the last element has an index of max-1

Comment: In other words, max=images.length (which is 5), and the items are indexes of 0,1,2,3,4.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

```
var images=["777777","666666","555555"];
var max = $(images).length;
var imgPtr = 0;

$('#swapnextimg').click{

   if (imgPtr == max) {
       //comment the below return and set imgPtr to 0 for rotating the images
       return;
   }

   $("#imageswap").attr('src', 'http://site.com/images/' + images[imgPtr++] + '.jpg');
}

$('#swapprevsimg').click{

   if (imgPtr == 0) {
       //comment the below return and set imgPtr to max-1 for rotating the images
       return;
   }

   $("#imageswap").attr('src', 'http://site.com/images/' + images[imgPtr--] + '.jpg');
}

<a id="swapnextimg"></a>
<a id="swapprevsimg"></a>
<div id="imagebox">
    <img id="imageswap" src="http://site.com/images/123456.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you've got one img tag, and only one. And that the purpose of this is to change that single image tag.

To do that you will need the nex and prev button.

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="#" data-num="" />
    <span class"prev">prev</span>
    <span class"next">next</span>  
</div>
```

The object:

```
var obj = [0: 'dog', 1: 'cat'];
```

now for the next and prev to work. We are going to take a look at the `.on()` method.

```
$('.container span').on('click', function(){
    var $this = $(this), // span
        currentNum = $this.siblings('img').data('num'), // img data-num
        nextNum = $this.is('.next') ? currentNum+1 : currentNum-1, // if class is next add 1, if not remove 1
        link = "http://site.com/images/" + obj[nextNum] + ".jpg" // the link

    // either it's not the last images or it returns
    nextNum != obj.length() || return 

    $('img').attr('src', link).data('num', nextNum)

})
```

Hope this helped you. If not please let me know

Comment: Are you assuming that the server provides incremental image IDs? That is not the case. Image IDs are random, generated GUIDs, non-incrementing. Sorry, I didn't make that clear in my question.

Comment: the object was just an illustration. If we take your array `var images=["777777","666666","555555"]`. If you `console.log(images[0])` you will print out `777777` in the console. That was what i was trying to illustrate, by manually providing the numeric keys. Does it make sense? Your array `images=["777777","666666","555555"]` is the same as `images=[0: "777777", 1: "666666", 2: "555555"]`