# Change Multiple Image Sources from Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, gallery

I am creating an image gallery where a user can click "next" and the images will update with the next images. All of the images should update to different images than were currently displayed.

For example once the next button is clicked:

> - Image01 --> Image04
> - Image02 --> Image05
> - Image03 --> Image06

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qecpthah/1/)

HTML:

```
 <div class="socialItem">
     <img class="socialImage" src="http://placehold.it/240.jpg" width="290" height="250" alt="" />
 </div>
 <div class="socialItem">
     <img class="socialImage" src="http://placehold.it/250.jpg" width="290" height="250" alt="" />
 </div>
 <div class="socialItem">
     <img class="socialImage" src="http://placehold.it/260.jpg" width="290" height="250" alt="" />
 </div>
 <a id="swapnextimg">Next</a>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function() {

    var images = ['240', '250', '260', '123', '200'];
    var max = images.length;
    $('#swapnextimg').click( function() {
        $(".socialImage").each(function(index) {
            console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).attr('src') );
            // Get current image src
            var curSrc = $(this).attr('src');

            // Find ID in image src
            var curID = curSrc.replace(/.*\/(.*?)\.jpg/i, '$1');

            var curIdx = 0;

            // Search image list for index of current ID
            while (curIdx < max) {
                if (images[curIdx] == curID) {
                    break;
                }
                curIdx++;
            }

            // For convenience
            var imgSrcBase = 'http://placehold.it/';

            // Next image on button (and image) click

            curIdx = (curIdx+1) % max;
            $(this).attr('src', imgSrcBase+images[curIdx]+'.jpg');
        });
    });
});
```

[This code is adapted partially from this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9489855/1248749)

I am attempting to use `.each` to incrementally replace the sources of each image individually that has the `socialImage` class. However it is instead replacing all of the images with that class at once.

Comment: What do you think is the value of `curID` when you are using `/.*\/(.*?)\.jpg/i` on `http://placehold.it/50/`? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can skip quite a lot of your code here.

```
$(function() {

    var images = ['240', '250', '260', '123', '200'];
    var max = images.length;
    var curIdx = -1;
    $('#swapnextimg').click( function() {
        $(".socialImage").each(function(index) {
            if(curIdx === -1) {
                var curId = $(this).attr('src').replace(/.*\/(.*?)\.jpg/i, '$1');
                curIdx = images.indexOf(curId);
            }

            // For convenience
            var imgSrcBase = 'http://placehold.it/';

            // Next image on button (and image) click

            curIdx = (curIdx+1) % max;
            $(this).attr('src', imgSrcBase+images[curIdx]+'.jpg');
        });
    });
});
```

On the first click, you look up the index of the first image.
After that you just keep incrementing the index by 1.